# I cannot import assets in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

The unity shows that" Identifier uniqueness violation: 'Name:, Type:Mesh'. Multiple Objects with the same name/type are generated by this Importer. There is no guarantee that subsequent imports of this asset will properly re-link to these targets."

And I cannot import the assets from the assets store.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue with the assets from the asset store having the same name i found an open issue on github of this exact issue, if you update unity to the latest version and change the name of the assets you are trying to import it will probably fix it. I will leave the link to the opened issue (it has been closed since then):

https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/issues/1973

This error seems to be an issue in newer unity versions but it has been since fixed:

https://forum.arongranberg.com/t/import-warnings-identifier-uniqueness-violation-for-minebot/8318